# Tcl callback from C/C++ with SWIG

Tags: c, tcl, swig

**Context**
I want to call a Tcl callback via SWIG from C/C++. More importantly, I want it to be a closure.

**Prior knowledge**
http://computer-programming-forum.com/57-tcl/4481cebe0f09966d.htm (no that wasn't me, just the only thing that seemed similar enough in a Google search)

With Python, I create an object on the Python side, give it a `__call__` method, chuck it through SWIG as a PyObject*, and it still has access to non-local variables as coded in Python (with a bit of glue code), because it's still intimately linked with the interpreter it was created in.

**My understanding (correct me here)**
In Tcl, the only way I'm calling a function from C is through a new interpreter by passing a string representing the command (but... then where's the closure...?). If I'm calling C/C++ from Tcl, still have the same problem, because C/C++ doesn't know about the calling Tcl interpreter.

Annnnddd... the documentation (http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/contents.htm), while extensive, is... well, really extensive. Collective knowledge please save me from my ignorance.

**Question** How do I get a closure/modify what value a name in Tcl is pointing to from C/C++? Or even just get a handle on an interpreter that's calling into C/C++ code...?

Comment: I'm trying to understand what pattern of calls you're trying for. Are you wanting to create a Tcl command that will call into some sort of closure on the C++ side when invoked?

Comment: And Tcl doesn't do closures (and that's awkward to fix because of the nature of values in Tcl; the language actually uses immutable references heavily). It does do coroutines and classes in 8.6, but they're _named_ entities; genuine values can't work that way.

Comment: At the first comment: yes. Second comment, h'okay, editing/ed the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understand in all this that Tcl's implementation is very much a C library, and so has C ways of doing things, not C++ ones. This might make

What you want is to put the C++ closure as a field in a `struct` that you allocate with `new`. You then cast the *pointer* to that `struct` as the `ClientData` argument to `Tcl_CreateCommand`; when the command is invoked, you'll get that pointer back as one of the arguments to the callback function, which you can then cast back to its real type and then invoke. When the command is deleted, you get another callback (if you ask for it) and that is a *great* time to `delete` the allocated `struct`. It sounds like a lot of work, but isn't actually.

I don't know exactly how to tie this into a nice SWIGgable approach, as I don't use either SWIG or C++ in my own production code. Maybe put the closure in a normal object and then SWIG that? However, under the covers it is the above that needs to happen. (The type of casts involved are `reinterpret_cast<…>`, unfortunately. `ClientData` is really just an alias for `void *` — unless you're using an ancient version of Tcl with an ancient compiler — along with the promise that the Tcl library code won't poke inside in any way.) I recommend using a `struct` because the whole space you've got to hang things off of is just one machine pointer's width in size. What's more, you can probably wrap everything up in a nice class to hide the gory details, but I can't really help you there as I'm no C++ guru.

Comment: From C it's easy. Put a pointer in the `ClientData` and you're done.

Comment: H'okay, so... I'm creating a command to retrieve from Tcl a command. I create this command in the interpreter that is registering a callback with my extension (but how do I get the interpreter calling into me if I'm an extension/Tclsh is the 'host'?). This command gets called, and it passes back to me the name of some callback (which presumably can mutate names... if I have a handle on the host interpreter). All of this seems conditional on me getting a handle on the host interpreter, which the Tcl docs aren't being particularly elucidating about. What do?

Comment: @Atash If your code is in a shared library that you want to incorporate into a Tcl interpreter, start at [the Wiki page for `load`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1208) and make sure to look at the “discussion” parts. Going in the other direction, you're embedding Tcl and a different set of guidelines apply (e.g., you have to care about library initialization).